# How to flatten a query string with htacess without affecting how php code

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, query-string

I would like to have a url like this

"www.site.com/?u=1" converted into this "www.site.com/1"

Without affecting my php scripts.

I'd also want to understand how and when does this conversion happen on the server.

**Here's what i've tried with no luck on the query string.**

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
#////////////Convert 'u' Query String////////////
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?u=$1 [NC]
#/////////////append www before all urls///////////////////////////
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
#///////////////////remove index.php from url/////////////
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming that any url on your website is looking like this: `www.site.com/?u=products/listing`. Then, you want the website to redirect the user to `www.site.com/products/listing`. My advice: You should edit the php files so that the browser doesn't redirect twice (1 load and 1 redirect) everytime a link is clicked, by means of htaccess. That what you want is only a hack, not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the `u` rule before your redirects. Those need to happen after the redirects:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

#/////////////append www before all urls///////////////////////////
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?u=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]

#///////////////////remove index.php from url/////////////
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

#////////////Convert 'u' Query String////////////
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Comment: OK finally it works, with two problems, when index.php is put in the address bar it redirects to www.site.com/1 HTTP/1.1 and again, it doesnt directly redirect to www.site.com/1, it just returns the right info as it does with the query string ?u=1.

Comment: Can we make to return www.site.com/1 when www.site.com/?u=1 is sent?

Comment: It's supposed to already do that (second rule). Have you cleared your browser's cache? 301 redirects are permanently cached by your browser

Comment: Yes i have, even used different browsers.

Comment: @Underscore needed to add a `\ ` to the brackets in the regex

Comment: still behaving the same way. May we should remove everything else and deal only with flattening the url.

Comment: @Underscore it works completely fine for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pxYWm.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/udvkT.png

Comment: ill check, maybe im doing something wrong. Let me accept ya answer