# How to flatten url with more than one query string using htacess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119409/how-to-flatten-a-query-string-with-htacess-without-affecting-how-php-code) question and got a great answer, just that i still don't understant how this happens. Maybe someone can explain this process and what each flag does.

So now i have,

```
site.com/index.php?query1=this&query2=that&query3=those and i want this translated into

site.com/song/this/that/those
```

Here's the existing code.

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
#/////////////append www before all urls///////////////////////////
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?u=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
#/////////////song
#///////////////////remove index.php from url/////////////
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
#////////////Convert 'u' Query String////////////
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add 2 more rules to handle 3 query strings (or 4 more if you want to also handle having 2 query strings).

The rule that checks `%{THE_REQUEST}` looks at the URL in the HTTP request, and matches against the query string (the `u=([^&\ ]+)`) and redirects the browser so that the new URL is displayed in the browser's location bar. The 2nd rule in the set internally rewrites the request *back* to having a query string, because your resource is at `index.php`.

So you'd add (under the `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]` rule):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?query1=([^&]+)&query2=([^&]+)&query3=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?query1=([^&]+)&query2=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```

to redirect the browser.

Then to internally rewrite the request back, add these rules to the end:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?query1=$1&query2=$2&query3=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?query1=$1&query2=$2 [L,QSA]
```